# How do you input an ASCII art image into the console in JS?

Tags: javascript, ascii

I'm trying to make this ASCII image shown in the console:

```
_______                                       
\  ___ `'.            /|                 .--. 
 ' |--.\  \           ||                 |__| 
 | |    \  '          ||                 .--. 
 | |     |  '         ||  __        __   |  | 
 | |     |  | _    _  ||/'__ '.  .:--.'. |  | 
 | |     ' .'| '  / | |:/`  '. '/ |   \ ||  | 
 | |___.' /'.' | .' | ||     | |`" __ | ||  | 
/_______.'/ /  | /  | ||\    / ' .'.''| ||__| 
\_______|/ |   `'.  | |/\'..' / / /   | |_    
           '   .'|  '/'  `'-'`  \ \._,\ '/    
            `-'  `--'            `--'  `"
```

However, I'm getting multiple errors since I do not know how you would input this to make it show up in the console when I activate the code.

Comment: Call `console.log()` to display the string in the console.

Comment: Are you asking how to put a multi-line string in your JavaScript source code? You can escape newlines with backslash, you can put `\n` in the string, you can use a template string.

Comment: You must use the backticks AND the font family monospace for ASCII art, see my answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a template literal to embed newlines in the string. You'll need to escape the backticks that are in the string.

```js
console.log(`_______                                       
\  ___ \`'.            /|                 .--. 
 ' |--.\  \           ||                 |__| 
 | |    \  '          ||                 .--. 
 | |     |  '         ||  __        __   |  | 
 | |     |  | _    _  ||/'__ '.  .:--.'. |  | 
 | |     ' .'| '  / | |:\`  '. '/ |   \ ||  | 
 | |___.' /'.' | .' | ||     | |\`" __ | ||  | 
/_______.'/ /  | /  | ||\    / ' .'.''| ||__| 
\_______|/ |   \`'.  | |/\'..' / / /   | |_    
           '   .'|  '/'  \`'-'\`  \ \._,\ '/    
            \`-'  \`--'            \`--'  \`" `);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the template string literal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

It can be done using the backtick charactere, example:

```js
console.log(`%c
_______                                       
\  ___ \`'.            /|                 .--. 
 ' |--.\  \           ||                 |__| 
 | |    \  '          ||                 .--. 
 | |     |  '         ||  __        __   |  | 
 | |     |  | _    _  ||/'__ '.  .:--.'. |  | 
 | |     ' .'| '  / | |:/\`  '. '/ |   \ ||  | 
 | |___.' /'.' | .' | ||     | |\`" __ | ||  | 
/_______.'/ /  | /  | ||\    / ' .'.''| ||__| 
\_______|/ |   \`'.  | |/\'..' / / /   | |_    
           '   .'|  '/'  \`'-'\`  \ \._,\ '/    
            \`-'  \`--'            \`--'  \`" 
`, `font-family: monospace`);
```

You must arrange the ASCII:

- escape every backticks, otherwise it will terminate the string.
- font used by the console is different than the one used by the ASCII image (monospace), in Chrome you can set the fonts, otherwise, you'll need to arrange the ASCII image to fit the console font.

> To view the font change, use the real console and not the one from StackOverflow

Answer (score 4):

Found this amazing [online converter](https://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html) which can be used to escape JavaScript string

Copy paste ASCII text to freeformatter, copy the escaped string to console.log("");

```
console.log("\r\n\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\r\n\u2588\u2588\u2554\u2550\u2550\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2588\u2588\u2554\u2550\u2550\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2588\u2588\u2554\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u2588\u2588\u2554\u2550\u2550\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2554\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2554\u2550\u2550\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2588\u2588\u2554\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u2591\r\n\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u255A\u2550\u255D\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2588\u2588\u2554\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2588\u2588\u2551\u255A\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2591\r\n\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2588\u2588\u2551\u255A\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u255A\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2554\u2550\u2550\u255D\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u2591\u255A\u2588\u2588\u2557\r\n\u255A\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2554\u255D\u255A\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2554\u255D\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2591\u255A\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2551\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2554\u255D\u255A\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2554\u255D\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2588\u2588\u2557\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2557\u255A\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2554\u255D\u255A\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2554\u255D\r\n\u2591\u255A\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u2591\u2591\u255A\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u2591\u255A\u2550\u255D\u2591\u2591\u255A\u2550\u2550\u255D\u255A\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u2591\u2591\u255A\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u2591\u255A\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u255A\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u255A\u2550\u255D\u255A\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u2591\u255A\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u2591\u2591\u255A\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\u2591")
```

Result

```
░█████╗░░█████╗░███╗░░██╗░██████╗░█████╗░██╗░░░░░███████╗░░░██╗░░░░░░█████╗░░██████╗░
██╔══██╗██╔══██╗████╗░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗██║░░░░░██╔════╝░░░██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██╔════╝░
██║░░╚═╝██║░░██║██╔██╗██║╚█████╗░██║░░██║██║░░░░░█████╗░░░░░██║░░░░░██║░░██║██║░░██╗░
██║░░██╗██║░░██║██║╚████║░╚═══██╗██║░░██║██║░░░░░██╔══╝░░░░░██║░░░░░██║░░██║██║░░╚██╗
╚█████╔╝╚█████╔╝██║░╚███║██████╔╝╚█████╔╝███████╗███████╗██╗███████╗╚█████╔╝╚██████╔╝
░╚════╝░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝╚═════╝░░╚════╝░╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝╚══════╝░╚════╝░░╚═════╝░
```

Comment: how do you create this long string? is there a tool where I can input "CONSOLE.LOG" and it will output me the string you posted in your answer? If freeformatter is the place to go then I was not successful finding the corresponding area. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @smartini for creating ASCII string, you can make use of sites like https://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=ANSI%20Shadow&t=consolelog, from there you can copy the ASCII equalaent of "consolelog" and paste that into https://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html to escape javascript

Answer (score 3):

You could also just use figlet. Make sure to install it first using npm i figlet

```
const figlet = require("figlet")
figlet.text("Text", function (err, data){
 console.log(data)
})
```

The code above is a function to send text to the module "figlet" and get the text back as ascii art. Try changing the "text" to see your outcome.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape both the back tick characters and the back slash characters.

```js
const str = `_______                                       
\\  ___ \`'.            /|                 .--. 
 ' |--.\\  \\           ||                 |__| 
 | |    \\  '          ||                 .--. 
 | |     |  '         ||  __        __   |  | 
 | |     |  | _    _  ||/'__ '.  .:--.'. |  | 
 | |     ' .'| '  / | |:/\`  '. '/ |   \\ ||  | 
 | |___.' /'.' | .' | ||     | |\`" __ | ||  | 
/_______.'/ /  | /  | ||\\    / ' .'.''| ||__| 
\\_______|/ |   \`'.  | |/\\'..' / / /   | |_    
           '   .'|  '/'  \`'-'\`  \\ \\._,\\ '/    
            \`-'  \`--'            \`--'  \`" `;
console.log(str);
```