# How to write a word in the console with the symbols?

Tags: javascript

On one of the millions websites I noticed big word in the console written with symbols. Which lib is that or how to do that? Cuz I have no idea.

[image]

###### It's just a plain text, you could select it (like I did) and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: There are several generators online to make a word out of multiple characters to make it big like that (related: ascii art). The colors are done with a css like syntax, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505623/12101554

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381195/how-do-you-input-an-ascii-art-image-into-the-console-in-js

Comment: https://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an ASCII generator, then wrap it using [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and then style it using CSS.

```js
console.log(`%c  

.d888 d8b                           888      d8b          
d88P"  Y8P                          888      Y8P          
888                                 888                   
888888 888 888d888 .d88b.  .d8888b  88888b.  888 88888b.  
888    888 888P"  d8P  Y8b 88K      888 "88b 888 888 "88b 
888    888 888    88888888 "Y8888b. 888  888 888 888  888 
888    888 888    Y8b.          X88 888  888 888 888 d88P 
888    888 888     "Y8888   88888P' 888  888 888 88888P"  
                                                 888      
                                                 888      
                                                 888      `,"font-family:monospace; color: orange;");
```

*This may not work in [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/22152755), but it should work locally.*

Answer (score -2):

You can do this with a template literal, using backticks.

```
console.log(`  _    _      _ _       
 | |  | |    | | |      
 | |__| | ___| | | ___  
 |  __  |/ _ \ | |/ _ \ 
 | |  | |  __/ | | (_) |
 |_|  |_|\___|_|_|\___/ 
                        
                        `);
```

Comment: needs backticks, won't work with single quotes like this

Comment: It'll result in `Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break`.